# Why the CameraUI in Adobe Air crashes sometimes on my device

Tags: actionscript-3, crash, camera

I built an action-script project and I added to it the cameraUI to take pictures, sometimes it works fine, and sometimes when launching, the app crashes by itself, I am pretty sure it's a memory leak somewhere in their code, can anyone help me solving the problem?

my device is iPhone 4s with the latest iOS 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I might have known the problem was from my device, I think that the memory has to be reset from time to time, I just restart the device and it worked fine, but that should be handled anyway.